# Macbook Pro 8.1 and Ubuntu conflict

Tags: 10.04, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid onto my Macbook Pro 8.1 over my Mac OS, and I am having many issues. The wireless is not working, the software update window will respond just long enough to get my hopes up, right click will not work, the mac hotkeys refuse to work, and the ubuntu software center spouts that all of the provided packages are "unverified", and outright refuses to let me install anything, even a software bit that worked on my last macbook/ubuntu install. HELP!?!?!?!

Comment: The MacBook Pro 8.1 is a pretty recent revision, isn't it?  10.04 is moderately old - certainly, before your hardware was produced - and so may well not support it properly.  I'd try an Oneiric (Ubuntu 11.10) LiveCD - the Release Candidate should be out in a couple of days.

Comment: Also, this is not really a question, so it's going to be hard for people to write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1046568):

`snippit`

Apple Intel Mac (Mactel) FAQ

Welcome to the Apple Users Forum at ubuntuforums.org.
This forum is focused on providing community support on the installation and setup of Ubuntu running on Apple hardware.

This FAQ is targeted at Users with a Intel-based Macintosh computers (mactel) with Core and Core 2 CPUs or Xeon. If you have a PowerPC-based Mac (G3, G4, G5) Please see the PowerPC FAQ. Please be sure to always check this FAQ and the Mactel-Support Community Support Documentation before asking a question in the forum, and when asking a question in the forum, post your Mac's version string.

- Can I run Ubuntu on my Mac?
  YES! You will have to reduce the size of your OSX partition in order to make room for Ubuntu.

  `Read more from the link above. It is very detailed and descriptive.`

[Ubuntu Documentation MacBook Pro 8.1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-1/Natty)

Answer (score 0):

Check here for specifics to that model - [Mac Book Pro 8,1 Natty](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-1/Natty)

I just installed 10.04 on my MB Pro model 5,1 and used the wiki for my model to get everything installed and running correctly.